# check if a df value exists in another df

Tags: python

I need to check if two dataframes contain the same value, and if they do then proceed

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'name': ['bob', 'alice', 'steve']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1], 'name': ['bob']})

df1 = df1['name']
df2 = df2['name']

print(df1)
print(df2)

if df2.isin(df1):
    print('yes')
```

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().